# User submitted rankings

Tags: algorithm, ranking

I was looking to have members submit their top-10 list of something, or their top 10 rankings, then have some algorithm combine the results. Is there something out there like that?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the vaguest question I have ever seen here. Or at least in the top-10.

Comment: Vague and specific at once. "What algorithmic ranking makes the most sense for aggregating a decent top 10 list?" Keep it open, the answers should be worthy.

Comment: In real life application, college football uses the combined rankings of the AP and coaches to determine their rankings. I haven't found anything that reveals what they use to combine the rankings, but would essentially like to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhhh, that's open-ended alright. Let's consider a simple case where only two people vote:

```
1  ALPHA
2  BRAVO
3  CHARLIE

1  ALPHA
2  DELTA
3  BRAVO
```

We can't go purely by count... ALPHA should obviously win, though it has the same votes as BRAVO. Yet, we must avoid a case where just a few first place votes dominate a massive amount of 10th place votes. To do this, I suggest the following:

```
$score = log($num_of_answers - $rank + 2)
```

First place would then be worth just a bit over one point, and tenth place would get .3 points. That logarithmic scaling prevents ridiculous dominance, yet still gives weight to rankings. From those example votes (and assuming they were the top 3 of a list of 10), you would get:

```
ALPHA: 2.08
BRAVO: 1.95
DELTA: .1
CHARLIE: .95
```

Why? Well, that's subjective. I feel out of a very long list that 4,000 10th place votes is worth more than 1,000 1st place votes. You may scale it differently by changing the base of your log (natural, 2, etc.), or choose a different system.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add up the total for each item of the ranking given by a user and then sort them.

ie:

```
A = (a,b,c)
B = (a,c,b)
C = (b,a,c)
D = (c,b,a)
E = (a,c,b)
F = (c,a,b)

a = 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 1 + 2 = 10
b = 2 + 3 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 3 = 14
c = 3 + 2 + 3 + 1 + 2 + 1 = 12
```

Thus,

1. a
2. c
3. b

Answer (score -1):

I think you could solve this problem by using a [max flow algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm), to create an *aggregate* ranking, assuming the following:

1. Each unique item from the list of items is a node in a graph. E.g. if there are 10 things to vote on, there are 10 nodes.
2. An edge goes from node *a* to node *b* if *a* is immediately before *b* in a _single user submitted_ ranking.
3. The last node created from a _single user submitted_ ranking will have an edge pointed at the *sink*
4. The first node created from a _single user submitted_ ranking will have an incoming edge from the *source*

This should get you an *aggregated* top-10 list.

Comment: I completely fail to comprehend how that is related. He's asking about how to rank them, but in step 2, you assume the ranking is determined.

Comment: In step 2, a ranking is "1  ALPHA,2  BRAVO,3  CHARLIE" just like you wrote.  I'll reworded my answer; let me know if it doesn't make sense.